# What is difference between upload speed and upload throughput?

Tags: selenium, networking, upload, throughput

I am trying to simulate different network speeds using selenium

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing the point of the question but:

"Bandwidth and throughput have to do with speed, but what's the difference? To be brief, bandwidth is the theoretical speed of data on the network, whereas throughput is the actual speed of data on the network."

Pretty much: bandwidth is what your ISP will market to you, but your throughput is what you'll actually get on your side, in terms of speed. Throughput will almost always be lower than the marketed/advertised bandwidth.

source:
[https://study.com/academy/lesson/bandwidth-vs-throughput.html#:~:text=Lesson%20summary,fast%20data%20is%20being%20sent.&text=Bandwidth%20refers%20to%20the%20theoretical,data%20on%20your%20network%20travels](https://study.com/academy/lesson/bandwidth-vs-throughput.html#:%7E:text=Lesson%20summary,fast%20data%20is%20being%20sent.&text=Bandwidth%20refers%20to%20the%20theoretical,data%20on%20your%20network%20travels).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the term *upload speed* in a broader aspect indicates the *internet speed* where for uploading and downloading you need speed. [*Bandwidth* and *Throughput*](https://study.com/academy/lesson/bandwidth-vs-throughput.html#:%7E:text=Lesson%20summary,fast%20data%20is%20being%20sent.&text=Bandwidth%20refers%20to%20the%20theoretical,data%20on%20your%20network%20travels.) are the two major indicators of speed where:

- *Bandwidth* is the theoretical speed of data on the network.
- *Throughput* is the actual speed of data on the network.

### Bandwidth

In true essence, *Bandwidth* refers to the maximum amount of data you can get from point A to point B in a specific amount of time. Thesedays while dealing with computers *Bandwidth* refers to, how many bits of information we can theoretically transmit in specific amount of time, as an example bits per second. E.g. **Kbps** (kilobits per second) and **Mbps** (megabits per second).

### Throughput

Throughput can only send as much as the bandwidth will allow and is actually less than that as factors like latency (delays), jitter (irregularities in the signal), and error rate (actual mistakes during transmission) reduces the overall throughput.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the method to do it.

Sets Chromium network emulation settings.

```
driver.set_network_conditions(
    offline=False,
    latency=5,  # additional latency (ms)
    download_throughput=500 * 1024,  # maximal throughput
    upload_throughput=500 * 1024)  # maximal throughput
    Note: 'throughput' can be used to set both (for download and upload).
```

[Source](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chromium/selenium.webdriver.chromium.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chromium.webdriver.ChromiumDriver.set_network_conditions)